# Multiple serial port DataReceived timeout

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, serial-port

First of all thanks for everybody who might be able to help me further on the following problem.

I am sending some text to several devices on serial port. Due to the already existing interface, I have to use DataReceived event to read the responses from the serial ports. There are devices that do not respond at all, so I need a timeout for waiting for the response.

So for a single device, I create an instance of SerialPort, add a handler to its DataReceived event and send my text and start a timer. Timer callback runs its own thread and I would like to run the DataReceived handler also in seperate thread.

When response comes before timer ticks, the timer needs to be stopped. When timer ticks before response comes, the late response should not be handled. So there are some shared data between timer and handler threads. How do I further go about synchronizing these two thread?

I also have to mention that I need to handle several devices simultaneously, that makes the threading situation even more complicated.

So far my code for handling a single device looks like this. Would appreciate greatly if somebody could further point me out how I should proceed about threading and synchronizing them.

```
    private void OnNewDeviceConnected()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(OnTimeOut, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", 9200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        serialPort.DataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            HandleReceivedData();
        };

        serialPort.Write("Text");
        _timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void OnTimeOut(object state)
    {
        // Do stuff on timeout
        _serialPort.Close();
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void HandleReceivedData()
    {
        // Do stuff on received text
        _serialPort.Close();
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

Comment: 'I also have to mention that I need to handle several devices simultaneously, that makes the threading situation even more complicated' - it should make it easier.  You have a separate port for each device?

Comment: Yes, I have separate port for each device. Each port has then its own processing thread I guess. It multiplies the number of threads created in my code. However, threads of different ports do not need to share data with each other.

Comment: SerialPort has a 'ReadTimeout' property.  Why use a timer?  Try and encapsulate everything to do with one port in one class, with thread/s inside if necessary.  Get it working correctly with one device/port. Then, for multiple devices/ports, just create an instance for each port.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Martin. I am not directly using a SerialPort class. Due to requirements, I needs to use a wrapper around SerialPort class and it only exposes the DataReceived event.

Comment: Ugh..  God save us all from inadequate tools/wrappers/subclasses:(

Comment: I'm trying very hard to not suggest a mutex-protected state-machine into which the OnTimeOut and HandleReceivedData both fire.  Incidentally, why close the port?  You only exchange data once?

Comment: Yes, I only need to send a text and receive the response to it. That's it.